# How powerapps quit azure sql connection?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sqlconnection, powerapps, azure-sql-server

We are using Azure SQL database in Powerapps. We suffered from extremely slow performance in one of our apps in previous days. Azure supports found out it may be the connection limitation of the plan. It improved after we scaled up the plan. We hope to minimize the same issue by exploring the possibility of killing the sql connection if the app is idle or press a button for example. Could powerapps do this? How powerapps quit a connection or could the connection be reused?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can reuse the connection to connect to a different table. Also I believe powerApps connection will be established on demand. If you use it in a gallery control it'll fetch 100 items first and do a lazy loading on scroll. But if you save it to a collection it'll fetch all items upto 2000 at one go which will impact performance

Comment: Thanks Ansar, which means nothing we can do in designing app in Powerapps but avoid loading too many records at a time to minimize the impact on the performance?

Comment: It depends how you are currently fetching the data. Is it saved in a collection first?

Comment: no, we get data instantly. Collection just stored temp data.

Comment: Try to limit the number of columns fetched by creating a view